# Linking Dynamic and Static Libraries Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am in the process of linking using a static library and dynamic library but, I run into this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: ../src/SeqLib/bin//libseqlib.a(libseqlib_a-FermiAssembler.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `_ZNSs4_Rep20_S_empty_rep_storageE' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

Here is how my Makevars file looks like:

```
( cd SeqLib; ./configure --enable-shared; make)
PKG_CPPFLAGS= -I../src/SeqLib/ -I../src/SeqLib/fermi-lite/ -I../src/SeqLib/htslib/cram/ -I../src/SeqLib/htslib/htslib/ -I../src/SeqLib/htslib/ -I../src/SeqLib/bwa/
PKG_LIBS=-fPIC -enable-shared-lib -L../src/SeqLib/bin/ -lbwa -lfml -lhts -lseqlib
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error when I included the `-fPIC` option in the `PKG_LIBS` variable.

Comment: Your question have nothing to do with Rcpp, really, but show problems you are having in creating a working R package (given your self-imposed constraints).  An oldie-but-goldie which has been doing this for well over a decade is the Matrix package and its [src/Makevars](https://github.com/cran/Matrix/blob/master/src/Makevars) may help you.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel "Your question have nothing to do with Rcpp," For the sake of other readers, how do you know this? What does this mean? The error states "recompile with -fPIC" after `devtools::load_all()`, even if this flag is included. This looks like an Rcpp problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21094740/linking-rcpp-to-interp2d-gsl-type-library

Comment: How to set up `src/Makevars` is pertinent for R packages using compiled code.  For Rcpp, we just use standard R build tools and instructions, and that is what you are having trouble with. And to be plain: the error message comes from the compiler, the tool you use to drive it may be `devtools`.  Again, no Rcpp in here.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel That makes sense. Thanks Jirk!

Comment: That is "Dirk" with a leading "D".

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I'm still not sure as to the right direction. I looked at the src/Makevars that you referenced but, I don't see any line that seems applicable to my example.

Comment: You aim to build a _shared_ library including an included _static_ library, and I showed you a package which has been dong that for many years.  When I struggle I often find it helpful to look at working solution to similar problems.  My claim is that this package pretty much does what you are struggling with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-fPIC` is a *compile only flag*.  If you include it when linking, the compiler will complaint about that.  If you are using a `Makefile` to compile your project (you have not included how do you use the variables cited in your question) the best approach is to define `-fPIC` in the `PKG_CFLAGS` in case your project contains only shared object targets.  I don't know the case of a Makevars, but probably the followind discussion will give you some hints on how to solve your problem.

If you are building programs and shared libraries, the best approach is to define a new `.SUFFIXES` dependency (let's call it `.pic_o`) and define a variable called `PKG_SHAREDCFLAGS=-fPIC` and then include a rule to compile those dependencies as this snippet shows:

```
PKG_SHAREDCPPFLAGS = -fPIC
.SUFFIXES: .pic_o
.c.pic_o:
    $(CPP) $(PKG_CPPFLAGS) $(PKG_SHAREDCPPFLAGS) -c $@ -o $<

libshared.so_objs = a.pic_o b.pic_o c.pic_o
libshared.so: $(libshared.so_objs)
    $(CPP) $(PKG_LDFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(libshared.so_objs) $(libshared.so_libs)
```

`.pic_o` are `.o` files compiled with the `PIC` flag (aka **P**osition **I**ndependent **C**ode) which is required for object files that are going to be part of a shared object.

It's not dangerous to compile all your code as `-fPIC`, as the linker has no problem to link PIC files statically into your code (position independent files only introduce a little overhead in your program, as the compiler reserves an offset register to control where the library has been finally loaded, and this gives you one register less to operate with)  The introduction of a new `.pic_o` suffix is to allow to produce static and dynamic versions of your library, so the static one only links objects compiled without `-fPIC` and the dynamic one uses the PIC ones.  Let's suppose you have a library, composed of `a.c`, `b.c` `c.c` files, and you want to produce a dynamic and a static library from them.  The following approach will success:

```
# All the targets.
targets=libA.a libA.so.3.0
TOCLEAN += $(targets)

# object files of the libA.a static library.
libA.a_objs = a.o b.o c.o
TOCLEAN += $(libA.a_objs)

# object files of the libA.so.3.0 dynamic library.
libA.so.3.0_objs = a.pic_o b.pic_o c.pic_o
TOCLEAN += $(libA.so.3.0_objs)
libA.so.3.0_libs = -lc

all: $(targets)
clean:
    rm -f $(TOCLEAN)

.PHONY: all
.SUFFIXES: .pic_o

libA.a: $(libA.a_objs)
    $(AR) -r $@ $?
    $(RANLIB) $@

.c.pic_o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -fPIC -c $< -o $@

libA.so.3.0: $(libA.so.3.0_objs)
    $(LD) -shared $(libA.so.3.0_objs) $(libA.so.3.0_libs) -o $@
```

And execution:

```
lcu@FreeBSD:~/pru_19091$ make clean all
rm -f libA.a libA.so.3.0 a.o b.o c.o a.pic_o b.pic_o c.pic_o
cc -O2 -pipe -c a.c -o a.o
cc -O2 -pipe -c b.c -o b.o
cc -O2 -pipe -c c.c -o c.o
ar -r libA.a a.o b.o c.o
ar: warning: creating libA.a
ranlib libA.a
cc -O2 -pipe -fPIC -c a.c -o a.pic_o
cc -O2 -pipe -fPIC -c b.c -o b.pic_o
cc -O2 -pipe -fPIC -c c.c -o c.pic_o
ld -shared a.pic_o b.pic_o c.pic_o -lc -o libA.so.3.0
```

Suppose I touch file `b.c`:

```
lcu@FreeBSD:~/pru_19091$ touch b.c
lcu@FreeBSD:~/pru_19091$ make 
cc -O2 -pipe -c b.c -o b.o
ar -r libA.a b.o
ranlib libA.a
cc -O2 -pipe -fPIC -c b.c -o b.pic_o
ld -shared a.pic_o b.pic_o c.pic_o -lc -o libA.so.3.0
```